# What offset for FAT32 in Photorec? Will it affect file recovery?

Tags: file-recovery

Im worrried a bad offset will cause Photorec to miss some files and/or recover them badly like for example a zip file.

How to fix a damaged zip file?

How to fix file names? (all names are plain gibberish)

Comment: If you don't have the data to repair a zip archive then it cannot be repaired.

Comment: @Ramhound I have most data so I would fix most archives if I would know what they are actually storing butthe filenames are something like f00784316.zip How can I find out the filenames?